# can I get sued without accepting EULA

Tags: licensing, terms-of-service, legal-terms, court, eula

I plan publishing information in an article about Software which is the result of people reverse engineering the software.

The author of the software has been attempting to sue people who made use of the information because it is **against the EULA**.

I do **not** have the software myself **nor** have I ever accepted the EULA. I am only using information I found on the internet (public websites, etc.) and write my article **based on my researches**.

My question is: Can I be sued for doing this because it is against the EULA which I never accepted?

The reason I am doing this is because it is a security threat for the users of the software however it needs more attention in order to be addressed by the company.

Answer (score 6):

No.

You cannot be held liable for violating the EULA if you have never used the software and are only reporting what people who did use it told you. Of course, people bring groundless lawsuits all the time and you might have to defend such a lawsuit if you are sued.

In some places you could be subpoenaed to disclose your sources, and in others, a reporter's privilege would allow you to quash such a subpoena.

Comment: I see frequently the question "can I be sued" to which the answer is usually YES. The appropriate question should be "can I be successfully sued" to which the answer is likely No, as you've posted. Any lawyer who takes on a case as described in the question should have his qualifications questioned by the appropriate agency.

Comment: @fred_dot_u This is correct, but keep in mind that someone can sue you in good faith and lose because they were unaware of a key fact (e.g. they assumed and sincerely believed you'd accepted the EULA even though you actually didn't, because another possibility didn't occur to them).

Comment: Thank your for your replies. Would be a URL to the forum entries or the username of the forum user who published the information be enough or do I need to have a real name etc.? What happens if the forum entry is removed, should I keep a downloaded file of the forum page?